# Access AWS CloudWatch Logs and Metrics Off-Prem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-backup

AWS allows us to capture all kinds of metrics and logs through CloudWatch. Are these data accessible outside the AWS cloud environment (assuming proper permissions and policies are set to allow it to be so)?

For example, could these data be backed up and stored on-prem?

I imagine a Lambda function could be created to access say S3 data and fetch it through the Gateway API, but are CloudWatch data stored in S3?

Answer (score 1):

Log data on CloudWatch is stored in S3 which we can not access. However, you can export log to S3.

[Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html) says..

> You can export log data from your log groups to an Amazon S3 bucket
> and use this data in custom processing and analysis, or to load onto
> other systems.
>
> ...
>
> To begin the export process, you must create an S3 bucket to store the
> exported log data. You can store the exported files in your Amazon S3
> bucket and define Amazon S3 lifecycle rules to archive or delete
> exported files automatically.

Then you can simply download from S3 or use services as you like.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I assume It’s also possible to schedule the movement of log data from the CloudWatch S3 to your custom S3, rather than do this manually each day or week or month?

Comment: For a periodically job, you can consider using Amazon EventBridge cron job.

Answer (score 1):

The raw metrics stored in **CloudWatch Metrics** are *not* accessible.

For example, when each Amazon EC2 instance sends `CPUUtilization` to CloudWatch.

Instead, **aggregated metrics** can be queried, such as "Average CPU Utilization over a 5-minute period".

This is different to **CloudWatch Logs**, which *can* be exported to Amazon S3.